# mysql table data output in a single row based on the type of the data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in mysql table called wallet_txns.

```
wlt_name   wlt_txn_type   wlt_txn_amount
A           Income              200
A           Expense             100 
B           Income              100
B           Income              500
B           Expense             200
```

I trying to get the output of the data like below ( the sum of income and expense in a single row)

```
Wlt_name    Expense       Income
A           100            200
B           200            600
```

I have used the following query, But i am not getting the output as expected, (the income and expense in getting in seperate rows) Please help...

```
select
    wlt_name,
    if(wlt_txn_type = 'Expense', wlt_txn_amount, 0) as Expense,
    if(wlt_txn_type = 'Income', wlt_txn_amount, 0) as Income
from wallet_txns
;
```

Comment: Have you heard about aggregation functions?

Comment: You want to sum the values but without using a 'sum' function? How? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already almost wrote correct query, but you forget about `sum` and `group`. Here query:

```
select
    wlt_name,
    sum(if(wlt_txn_type = 'Expense', wlt_txn_amount, 0)) as Expense,
    sum(if(wlt_txn_type = 'Income', wlt_txn_amount, 0)) as Income
from wallet_txns
group by wlt_name
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can help this part of the code: `SUM(IF(wlt_txn_type = "Income", wlt_txn_amount, 0)) AS IncomeTotal`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conditional sum` and then `group by`

```
select 
wlt_name, 
sum(
 case when wlt_rxn_type ='Income' then wlt_txn_amount else 0 end
) as `Income`,
sum(
 case when wlt_rxn_type ='Expense' then wlt_txn_amount else 0 end
) as `Expense` 
from wallet_txns group by wlt_name;
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot put the 'sum'. Thanks to all for reminding and supporting.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    Wlt_name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN wlt_txn_type='Expense' THEN wlt_txn_amount ELSE 0 END) AS Expense,
    SUM(CASE WHEN wlt_txn_type='Income' THEN wlt_txn_amount ELSE 0 END) AS Income
FROM
    wallet_txns
GROUP BY
    Wlt_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mysql user, but TSQL has little secrets to me. Check for PIVOT - UNPIVOT alternatives on the WWW.